# Disable strict mode in a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

In my PowerShell profile, I have `Set-StrictMode -Version 2.0`. Unfortunately, I have some scripts (and modules) that don't work correctly with strict mode enabled.

I've attempted to fix this by putting `Set-StrictMode -Off` at the top of the scripts, or at the top of scripts that use the misbehaving modules. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to have any effect.

How do I temporarily disable strict mode in PowerShell?

**More detail:** This specifically occurs with PsGet. See [issue 57](https://github.com/psget/psget/issues/57). I have `Set-StrictMode -Version 2.0` in my profile. If I attempt to use PsGet's `Install-Module` from a script, I get errors saying "Property 'Verb' cannot be found on this object."

This occurs even if I put `Set-StrictMode -Off` at the top of the script. If I run `Set-StrictMode -Off` at the command line before running the script, I get no errors and the script works fine.

PsGet is imported in my profile, before turning on strict mode.

Comment: Are you sure that it's Set-StrictMode that's causing the errors to occur? I'm guessing you've tested the same scripts after having removed it from your $profile? I've been trying to replicate the issue, but I can always override my $profile by explicitly calling it in the script or console.

Comment: I've added more detail in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Like Matt says in the comments, I do not see this issue reproduce.  Can you provide more details?

Contents of `StrictModeTest.ps1`:

```
Set-StrictMode -Off

# variable $x doesn't exist, should trigger strictmode error
"Value is [$($x.Path)]"
```

Testing (PSv3):

```
PS C:\> Set-StrictMode -Version 2.0
PS C:\> .\StrictModeTest.ps1
Value is []
```

If I comment out the `Set-StrictMode -Off` line, I get the expected error:

```
PS C:\> .\StrictModeTest.ps1
The variable '$x' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
At C:\StrictModeTest.ps1:4 char:14
+ "Value is [$($x.Path)]"
+              ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (x:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableIsUndefined

Value is []
```